# Does the temperaure anomaly correlate with solar irradiance?

Tags: climate-change, climatology

[image]

([source](https://www.friendsofscience.org/assets/documents/Soon_CC2015_preprint.pdf))

Just wanted to know of its validity. Would be helpful.

Comment: I found the same image via Google image search in this PDF on page 37: https://www.friendsofscience.org/assets/documents/Soon_CC2015_preprint.pdf (Needless to say, it's a climate change denial website)

Comment: More a duplicate of https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35963/is-half-of-the-climate-change-in-the-past-110-years-due-to-natural-variation-in/35988#35988